# Default Download Directory Not changing with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do web scraping to download a file from MS webpage. I am using Selenium webdriver to achieve this using chrome. But whatever I do, the downloaded file automatically gets saved under the default Downloads folder. Below is the code I am using to achieve this, with Selenium v4.11.2

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080");    
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    
    chrome_prefs = {"download.default_directory": download_dir, "download.directory_upgrade": True, "savefile.default_directory": download_dir}
    chrome_options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
    
    #service = Service(executable_path='C:\Python_Works\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
   
    time.sleep(5)
```

Selenium version on my computer:[image]

Could someone please advise where exactly I am wrong here. Do I need to have admin privileges to change the default download directory, as this is my work laptop?